# Iframe scroll bar duplicated?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

On these two URL's of my site,

- http://www.infinite-possibility.com/kimkorn
- http://www.infinite-possibility.com/joepine

I pull in an iframe into the page. You will notice how there are two scroll bars, the default one for the wordpress theme (handled by a jQuery plugin) and then the iframe one... Obviously this does not look good..

Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer scroll bar is on your `<div class="main">`, because the content inside that fixed-size div is too large for the available area.

Within that, you've got your iframe, which has a site which contains a fixed-size div that also has overflow.

You cannot do anything in your css to affect the iframe's contents, because the contents of the iframe are quite literally a completely different web page (linkedin), with its own independent css.

Comment: so would it be possible to disable the scroll bar that is in <div class="main"> on just that page?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your height, margins and padding right. There are blank spaces unused outside the iframe.